# Is this right way to set backend configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, cors

In example bellow, I have backend setup for my application, but I have problem probably with CORS.

So problem is that my cookie won't set in the browser, I tested this on the Postman and Insomnia everything is clear, I think reason for this is because Postman and Insomnia ignore CORS, but brwsers don't do that.

I don't know is my backend good and should I change something, I try some other stuff like allowing * adresses, adding properties to `app.use(cors());` and nothing helped.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const logoutRouter = require("./routes/logout");
const vehicleRouter = require("./routes/vehicle");
const dashboardRouter = require("./routes/dashboard");

app.use(express.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(cors());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    key: "userId",
    secret: "sistem",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);

app.use("/", authRouter);
app.use("/", usersRouter);
app.use("/", logoutRouter);
app.use("/", vehicleRouter);
app.use("/", dashboardRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server je pokrenut");
});
```

I hope you can help me with this and finally solve this error.

BTW, this is my whole index.js file other routes are in the separate folders as like DB connection, I think this is much cleaner way to do thid.

Comment: `https` in localhost? Are uusing self-cerrtificate?

Comment: if you `app.use(cors());` you don't really need to add the CORS headers yourself - what is the EXACT error you receive

Comment: @PauloGuimarães my bad for https, it should be http.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't get any error, reaction is that because my cookie doesn't set in the browser without using --disable-web-security

Comment: First, rely on Express's CORS middleware library and do not manually add CORS headers. Second, a necessary condition for cookies to get set is to allow credentialed access in your CORS configuration; with Express, use `credentials: true`. You will also need to explicitly allow the Web origin of your frontend: something like `origin: 'https://yourfrontend.com'`. See https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors

Comment: oh, you said "*probably* with CORS" ... I assumed it was CORS

Comment: @JaromandaX yup, because test on Postman and Insomnia works fine, but these two ignore CORS, so I thought that is problem

Comment: Not all user agents implement the SOP (and CORS). Browsers do, but Postman and Insomnia do not.

Comment: @jub0bs is there a way to fix this, or even disable CORS?

Comment: Is right way for me to set these info with localStorage, i just need some user data, like username, first name, surname and etc?

Comment: No. Not enabling CORS != disabling the Same-Origin Policy. You need to figure out why your cookie isn't being set. CORS will be part of the solution.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here even is CORS problem here